# c# Форматирование числа (ИНН) в строку

Tags: c#, format

Есть числовое(decimal) поле ИНН (10, 12 символов).
Первые 2-а числа в ИНН - код региона.

Мне надо его превратить в строку.
Если длина строки 9 или 11 символов, то дописать 0.

Можно ли это сделать сразу в выражении ToString()?

INN.ToString("#.##")

Comment: inn.ToString("000000000000"); //12 нулей, для пущего понимания предоставьте данные, подумаем.

Comment: А зачем вам ИНН decimal? ИНН это строка а не число, и даже не число с плавающей точкой.

Comment: Все понимают, что ИНН строка, но есть некий работающий код, в некой коробочной программе, который уже наплодил кучу записей.
Обновлять программу по всем клиентам пока не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 1):

Если уже есть использование преобразования в `SQL` тогда почему бы не преобразовывать сразу в `string`?
К самому `string`'у уже можно дописать метод расширения:

```
public static class MyExtention
{
    public static string ToINN(this string str)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return str;
        string prefix = "000";
        string res = prefix + str;
        return str.Length <= 9 ? res.GetLast(10) : res.GetLast(12);
    }
    public static string GetLast(this string source, int tail_length)
    {
        if (tail_length >= source.Length)
            return source;
        return source.Substring(source.Length - tail_length);
    }
}
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string inn1 = "999999999",  //9
               inn2 = "11111111111";//11
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Old INN {0}(l={2}), new INN {1}(l={3})", inn1, inn1.ToINN(), inn1.Length, inn1.ToINN().Length));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Old INN {0}(l={2}), new INN {1}(l={3})", inn2, inn2.ToINN(), inn2.Length, inn2.ToINN().Length));
    }

}
```

Результат работы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может быть я не правильно понял место добавления нулей (в конец или сначала). Но это уже все можно переделать под свои хотелки

Comment: Про immutable string я промолчу, памяти везде много.
Но мне моё решение нравится больше - стандартными средствами форматирования чисел, кода меньше, чище и понятнее.

Comment: а как код поведёт себя для корректных значений?
когда регион состоит из 2-х цифр?
в этой ситуации к ИНН юрика (10 цифр) будет добавлено 000 и результат станет
001234567890

Comment: дело Ваше. но проверка `inn > 10000000000` мне очень не нравится. Посмотреть как поведет себя код при разных значениях можете сами (так же как и дописать проверки для обхода данной ситуации)

Comment: так что не так с этой проверкой?

это строго однозначно отделит юрика от физика.
если же получать из SQL строки, то гораздо проще написать расширение, которое для длины строки 9 и 11 дописывает вначале "0"

Answer (score 0):

Решил не использовать `decimal`.

Из базы при получении данных делаю

```
cast(field as bigint) as INN
```

далее в коде

```
inn > 10000000000 ? inn.Value.ToString("D12") : inn.Value.ToString("D10")
```

Всем спасибо.

Comment: сомнительное решение

Comment: Юрий, предложите лучше.